# Can a Django YearArchiveView return a list of all possible years?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm using **[`YearArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#yeararchiveview)** with an app I've created to show all reviews from each year on a page:

```
class year_reviews(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = SimpleReview.objects.published()
    date_field = "date_published"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = False
    template_name = 'reviews.html'
    context_object_name = 'reviews'
```

The view works fine - it correctly returns all reviews for the year specified in the URL, doesn't show future reviews, and only shows published reviews.

On the top of the rendered page I'd like to have a list of all years with reviews, so that the user can easily move to a different year's reviews. `YearArchiveView` automatically provides `next_year` and `previous_year` context variables to the template, but I can't find any sort of list of all years available. `date_list` looked promising, but only returns a list of *months* within the selected year.

Is there any way to get a list of all years that could be displayed by the view, so as to provide navigation between pages for the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - a `dates` queryset can do this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates

It doesn't look like anything in the generic view already runs such a query, so you'll probably want to put it in your `get_context_data` method.

You'll want something like this:

```
class YearReviews(YearArchiveView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(YearReviews, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['years_available'] = self.queryset.dates(self.date_field, 'year')
        return context
```

That'll put a queryset of `datetime.date` objects into your context, representing January 1 of each valid year. If you like, you could turn them into year strings in the `get_context_data` method, or use the `|date` filter in your template. It ignores your `allow_future` setting - this is probably not a big deal if you're basing your publication dates on real time.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn about class-based views, so I'm familiar with `get_context_data`, but I'll look into this and see if there's a way I can tie a custom queryset in with that. Thanks.

Comment: Edited in a little more detail.

Comment: I gave something like this a try, but because my `date_published` is a DateTimeField not a DateField, I'm running into a bug ([#21432](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21432)) that causes an error when trying to use the `datetimes()` method on a queryset. The bug has been fixed but it isn't in Django 1.6 (production) which is what I'm using, so I can't really test this until I figure out a way around that bug. Thanks for the help - I'll update once I get that issue fixed.

Comment: Looks like that bugfix made it into Django 1.6.1, which I've just installed, and this works! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I haven't actually worked with that recent a Django release. Finding the official bug report was absolutely the right move, btw.